# What's a clever way to stop old windows from rattling?

Tags: windows

My old wooden windows rattle in their casings (the frame rattles in its tracks--the glass is secure). One suggestion was to use vinyl flooring as shims--that material would be too thick, but I'm wondering if there's something similar that would work. Any suggestions for a durable thin material I can find at a big box construction store? Or another solution altogether?

Comment: Browse the weather-stripping collection.some combination of foam, felt, tubing, and hdpe V-strips should do the job. If all else fails, putty them in place.

Comment: The wooden frames rattle? Or the glass panes rattle in the frame?

Comment: I think I'd be going with a very small, precisely-applied bead of clear pure silicone caulk.

Comment: If it's the glass, then the window panes are held in place with glazing and the glazing can be replaced to make it snug.  But if it's the wood frames, caulk would seal the window shut and be a horrible idea...

Comment: Good point. I assumed the glass. That said, the question is a bit unclear. Photos would help.

Comment: You can get plastic shim stock in nearly any thickness you can imagine.  Perhaps a few strips of the proper thickness will suffice here.

Comment: Sorry, the glass is fine, it's the windows in their tracks. I thought those tracks were casings but I was probably using the wrong term. Channels? @CarlWitthoft, what department would I look for plastic shim stock in? What is it sold as, or sold for?

Comment: Very thin plastic can be had for the cost of cutting up a couple of lids from plastic deli containers. Or if you have to go buy stuff, google 'UHMW tape'. Or move the stops in to secure the window properly (though of course that'll involve paint/patch work).